# cleaning out leading zeros in file using vim regexp

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file containing 16bit hex numbers. Numbers are like `0000, fa01, 00f1,0001` etc. I wanted to remove the leading 0s so that i am left with just the numbers for instance `0000` should be changed to just `0` and `0001` should be changed to `1` and `0` should be left unchanged.

I am trying with a regexp like this `%s/^0\+\(0$\)\@!//`. This leaves a line blank in case there is some number like this  `000`. Any suggestion on how to fix this regrexp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably something like this:

```
:0,$ s/0\+\([0-9a-f]\)/\1/
```

Any number of zeros, but keep at least one digit... without the `g` flag it will do it once per line at most.

Of course, use A-F too if there are upper case in your hex.

---

**Update:**

The `\(0$\)\@!` says match the last zero on the line and then negate that making it **false** (hopefully).

However, looking at the expression closely the zero is taken in the `0\+`, then the `0$` returns false and the `\@!` negates that! Therefore it is a match. So I would think that your expression worked okay except for all zero expressions.

Comment: The solution you have provided works. Thanks. By the way could you please tell me why the regexp i was using earlier `%s/^0\+\(0$\)\@!//` was not working?